# Two ListView in activity _main.xml . I am not getting both same at a same time

Tags: android, json, xml, listview, slider

I have activity_main.xml in app. which consist of two listview. one is responsible for json data view as a list with customlist adapter another one is for displaying content of side menu .
Via one listview i am getting json data but not getting side menu content by second listview if i have declared in activity_main.xml.
I am not getting what are the reason behind it? Please help .

[image: after clicking profile]
[3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG23L.png)

[image: Main Screen]

[image: Sidemenuscreen]
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/app_name"
    >


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.About;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.CurrencyConverter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.EMICalculator;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Feedback;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.NavDrawerItem;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.PayInstallment;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Profile;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Settings;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.SocialFeed;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    //  drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adater1;


    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // data of json url
    private static final String url = "http://milagro.in/wip/apps/n/THDC2.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("tata_project_name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("project_logo_url"));
                                movie.setParkingUrl(obj.getString("parking"));
                                movie.setPowerbackupUrl(obj.getString("powerbackup"));
                                movie.setFitnessUrl(obj.getString("fitness"));
                                movie.setLiftUrl(obj.getString("lift"));
                                movie.setParkUrl(obj.getString("park"));
                                movie.setSecurityUrl(obj.getString("security"));
                                movie.setSwimmingUrl(obj.getString("swimming"));
                                movie.setTypology(obj.getString("project_Typology"));
                                movie.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        //addListenerOnButton();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Profile
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // About
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Emi Calculator
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Currency Converter
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // PayInstallments/EMI
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Social Feed
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        // Feedback
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        //Settings
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adater1 = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adater1);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menu, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
//          displayView(0);
        }
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Profile();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new About();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new EMICalculator();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new CurrencyConverter();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PayInstallment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new SocialFeed();
                break;
            case 6 :
                fragment =new Feedback();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment =new Settings();
            break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    public void bottomMenuClick(View v)
    {
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

        switch (pos)
        {
            case 1: // enquiry screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Enquiry.class));
                break;
            case 2: // contact screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contact.class));
                break;
            case 3: // Instant Call Back screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallBack.class));
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
```

profile.java(side menu  content )

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;

public class Profile extends Fragment {

    public Profile(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Profile"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you closed your Framelayout tag, it is a container and must contain the json data listview.

Comment: Thanks.I have closed after list view of json data. But after clicking of side menu list particular screen is not replacing json data list view .

Comment: see in attached image. if i am closing Framelayout after listview of json then on click of profile side menu content should be replace list view of json data but it is not happening .it is coming over List view of json . why ? please tell  me

Comment: You are using a drawerlayout, it slides a listview half way over your content, it wont replace the content listview

Comment: then what should i use ? Could you please tell me ?

Comment: There 2 things you can do, have 2 adapters and when clicked on the menu, change the main listview adapter and back. And the other thing is, have a relative layout with 2 listview and hide one when clicked and show the other one

Comment: Although i dont know exactly why you want to do that, what you have right now is the correct android design pattern...

Comment: UI element called DrawerLayout for Navigation Drawer. 
I have used for side menu screen.

Comment: Thank you @Ashkan Ghodrat. I got solution . I have posted answer & snapshot for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update in activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/app_name"  >


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

changes in profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Profile"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In profile click, background transparency issue which is solved by adding android:background="#FFFFFF".

[image: after clicking opening the content]